# Mobile operator unique identifier

Tags: mobile, routes, telephony, lte

I don't know if it's an appropriate place to ask this question, hope it is.

I'm looking for a way to uniquely identify a mobile operator in the world. I'm aware of the **MCC/MNC** tuple, unfortunately big mobile operators might have more than one **MNC**.

I found an identifier called **TADIG**(or sometimes **PLMN CODE**), but unfortunately **GSMA** standard says that there is one to one mapping between **MCC/MNC** tuple to **TADIG** identifier and again it means that one mobile operator might have more than one **TADIG**(of course I checked and found that it's not unique).
String comparison between mobile operator names doesn't seem like a good solution, there are different naming conventions around the internet for the same operator.

Does anyone know of any unique id that mobile operators might have?
Thanks.

Comment: _same MNC may even get used by few mobile operators_ Can you provide link for this information?

Comment: @cse actually this information is wrong, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: So I guess your problem is solved. You have `many-to-one` relationship i.e. multiple `MCC/MNC` belongs to same `MNO`. But no `MCC/MNC` belongs to more than 1 `MNO`.

Comment: The problem I guess is that there is no available free information that map MNO to all of their avaliable MCC/MNC tuples, mcc-mnc.com has incomplete/not updated information and mobile operator names are inconsistent across different tuples(for example one tuple can be Verizon and the second one will be VZ) so it makes it difficult to create a consistent mapping. I guess there is no way but to pay GSMA to get this info.

Comment: I don't think GSMA have `MNC` list. It only have `MCC` lists. Though I'm not sure. Did you visited [http://www.mcc-mnc.com](http://www.mcc-mnc.com/)? I think it provides enough info.

Comment: Yes, I definitely did, I found that it is not updated(last updated in 2013) and encountered missing tuples. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

The probable solution is if the MNOs (mobile carriers) publish their ip block publicly, then we can try to group them by ips and map them to MNOs. But problem is

- Its not publicly available
- It tends to change every now and
  then and MNOs don't really care about updating them.

I tried using combination of ASN, ipslash24, MCC-MNC but they weren't really useful. Let me know if you find anything.